# How is it possible to add icons to my UItextfield?

Tags: swift4, xcode9

[image]

I would very much appreciate the help :), and also is there any way to make the underline change colors when entering a username or password?

Comment: UITextfield has rightView, leftView property, so you can add any custom UIView to UITextfield

Comment: Refer this https://github.com/SwifterSwift/SwifterSwift/blob/master/Sources/Extensions/UIKit/UITextFieldExtensions.swift

Comment: thank you I will take a look at this

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below code:

```
    let iconWidth = 20;
    let iconHeight = 20;

    //Define the imageView
    let imageView = UIImageView();
    let imageEmail = UIImage(named: "xyz.png");
    imageView.image = imageEmail;

    // set frame on image before adding it to the uitextfield
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: iconWidth, height: iconHeight)
    textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
    textField.leftView = imageView
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIImageView and this too as a subview inside the UITextField